# Facebook SDK - settings.jar not found

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-studio, sdk

So I downloaded the latest Facebook SDK from the Facebook Developer website (4.1.2)
and when I tried to import it in to my Android Studio Project, I get an error saying

'Cannot find file `C:\Users\blah blah blah\Desktop\facebook\facebook-android-sdk-4.1.2\settings.jar`'

Does anyone know what's wrong and is there a fix?

Thank you.

Comment: once you're using android studio with gradle, it's more appropriate to use maven/jCenter dependency : like this : 

dependencies { 
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
}

Comment: That's the thing.. I have done that :/

And now in my Terminal it is saying my 'keytool' is not recognised as an internal or external command?

Comment: so you have to add the `keytool` to your path from you java bin directory ( C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\keytool.exe )

Comment: This is so frustrating! I basically did a complete uninstall of Android Studio - Installed it again and created a new project and it is still displaying the same message. I can't even import V7/appcompat.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `Android Studio` add the dependency to the `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies { 
      compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.2' 
      }
```

if you have this just make a `Synchronize` (clean & build)

[image]

Comment: I did that too. BUILD SUCCESSFUL it said

Comment: and are you sure to have this file in the specified path?  C:\Users\blah blah blah\Desktop\facebook\facebook-android-sdk-4.1.2\settings.jar

Comment: Yep. Although there is a 'settings.gradle' in the FB SDK folder and a 
'settings.jar' in my config folder which is in my AndroidStudio1.2 folder

Comment: This is so frustrating! I basically did a complete uninstall of Android Studio - Installed it again and created a new project and it is still displaying the same message. I can't even import V7/appcompat. –

Comment: remember that you have to add the dependencies in gradle.file : dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
}

Comment: Okay sorry for being such a noob and a pain in the a** - But I have two gradle.file. 

One is 
'build.gradle (Project:TestApplication)' and the other one is 
'build.gradle (Module: app) -   <<<I am guessing it's this one.. since it says I can't add the dependencies in the other one?